# Oneness of different Indian philosophical thoughts

Tags: philosophy, shad-darshana

Do six schools of Indian Philosophy accommodate each other or are they watertight compartments each to the exclusion of other?

Comment: None of the answers have been satisfactory.The answer failed to address the fundamental aspect of the question.

Comment: that's because this is not a simple question/answer.. it's like asking to prove fermat's last theorem in a internet forum. You could learn Brahma Sutras from an acharya (by personally visiting and serving them humbly), if you're truly inclined. It details all different schools and how to refute and arrive at conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Historically, Indians had always accepted a diversity of traditions. Unfortunately, in the Kali Yug, tolerance is at it's end.

For example, let's us take the issue of Beef eating:

1. Vedic Age: Male Cows were sacrificed and eaten as Prasadam -https://archive.org/details/textswhiteyajur00grifgoog
2. 300 BC: Emperor Ashok published edict not to eat Cows
3. 1st millenium AD: Defying Vedic scripture, a new caste was created specifically for beef eaters, hunters, butchers, executioners & fishermen:   Asprasya ([Untouchables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untouchability)) -https://www.pahujalawacademy.com/lectures-of-history/
4. British Raj: Asprasya were discriminated against, and named as [Dalit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalit). -http://ijmsrr.com/downloads/1704201665.pdf
5. 2017 AD: People are murdered for being suspected of killing a Cow. -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_vigilante_violence_in_India_since_2014

The "watertight compartments" are not philosophical barriers, but the modern definition of Castes and Sub-Castes(Jats).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, What's the need to mention Cows here?

Comment: The idea that a new caste was created solely for the exclusion of certain members of the community exemplifies tolerance in Kali Yug.

Comment: What, Vedic tradition does not allow eating cows.

Comment: Vedic Tradation only prohibits the eating of Milk-giving cows; NOT all cows.

Comment: " 43) Here have the cows been called to us, the goats and sheep have been called near, 
And in our home we have addressed the meath that sweeteneth our food. 
I come to thee for safety and for quiet. May joy be ours, felicity, and blessing. 
44) We invocate the Maruts, the voracious, eaters of their foes, Delightiug in their mess of meal. 
45) We expiate by sacrifice each sinful act that we have done,
 Whether in village or the wild, in company or corporeal sense. !Swaha! " 
-YAJURVEDA, as translated by RALPH T. H. GRIFFIT